# Rails: Associations between playlists and users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have a playlist, user, and song model. A song can be in any number of playlists, a playlist can be shared amongst users but can also have multiple "owners" that have the right to modify them. What would be the best way to model this with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
```

Playlist:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :songs
```

Song:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
```

Then you need to create join tables between the models. Important is to explicit exclude the id like this:

```
create_table :users_playlists, :id => false do |t|
     t.integer :user_id, :playlist_id
end
```

// Edit

You can also generate a table for users that should have edit rights:

Add this to Playlist:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :editor_users, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

And this to User:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :editable_playlists, :class_name => 'Playlist', :foreign_key => 'playlist_id'
```

Comment: That looks like something I have at the moment, still, how do I specify who will be allowed to modify the playlist? The playlist should be read-only to the users that don't have the rights to change it.

Comment: Updated post, should word like that